# "Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation" error when working with schoology API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, schoology

I'm building a planner app and trying to integrate it with schoology's API. I'm using this GitHub repository https://github.com/hieyou1/schoology-api and I'm getting an unexpected error when I'm calling to request a token.

Here is what this section of my code essentially looks like:

```
import { SchoologyAPI } from 'schoology-api';//https://github.com/hieyou1/schoology-api
const client_key = "1234";
const secret = "000";
const client = new SchoologyAPI(client_key, secret, "https://schoology.[SchoolName].org/");

async function getClient () {
     client.getRequestToken()
}
export default function CreateHeader(){
getClient();
}
```

It says its an illegal invocation and it seems to be a problem with the repository in the index.ts file on line 112 which is the function `getRequestToken()`.

```
  async getRequestToken(): Promise<Token> {
        const Authorization = this.getUnsignedAuthHeader();
        let res = await (await this.fetch(this.api_base + '/oauth/request_token', {
            headers: { Authorization }
        })).text();
        const token = qsParse(res);
        this.setToken(token);
        return token;
    }
```

I've tried changing the `client.getRequestToken()` to `client.getRequestToken.call()`, but then it says it can't read the `getUnsignedAuthHeader()`  function in the repository

I've attempted to use solutions in the [Fetch TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720448/fetch-typeerror-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-window-illegal-invocation) question, but none of them seemed to work.

Here is the complete code from the repository that I'm using

```
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import { isBrowser as IS_BROWSER } from "is-in-browser";
const qsParse = (search: string): any => {
    return Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(search).entries());
};
const DEFAULT_SITE_BASE = 'https://www.schoology.com';
const SCHOOLOGY_API_HOST = 'https://api.schoology.com';
const SCHOOLOGYTEST_API_HOST = 'https://api.schoologytest.com';
const REALM_PARAM = { 'OAuth realm': 'Schoology API' };

type SigMethod = 'HMAC-SHA1' | 'PLAINTEXT';

type FullToken = {
    oauth_consumer_key: string,
    oauth_nonce: string,
    oauth_signature_method: SigMethod,
    oauth_timestamp: number,
    oauth_token: string,
    oauth_version: '1.0',
};

type Token = {
    oauth_token: string;
    oauth_token_secret: string;
};

const headerFormat = (components: Record<string, string | number>) => {
    const parts: string[] = []
    Object.keys(components).forEach(key => parts.push(key + '="' + components[key] + '"'))
    return parts.join(',')
};

const baseStringFormat = (components: Record<string, string | number>) => {
    const parts: string[] = []
    Object.keys(components).forEach(key => parts.push(key + '=' + components[key]))
    return parts.join('&')
};

export class SchoologyAPI {
    client_key: string
    client_secret: string
    site_base: string
    api_base: string
    oauth_token: string
    oauth_token_secret: string
    redirectLoop: boolean;
    fetch: (url: any, init: any) => any;

    constructor(client_key: string, client_secret: string, site_base = DEFAULT_SITE_BASE, api_host: string = null) {
        if (IS_BROWSER) {
            this.fetch = window.fetch.bind(window)
        } else {
            this.fetch = require("node-fetch");
        }
        this.client_key = client_key;
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
        this.site_base = site_base;
        this.api_base = `${(api_host ?? ((site_base.indexOf('schoologytest') !== -1) ? SCHOOLOGYTEST_API_HOST : SCHOOLOGY_API_HOST))}/v1`;
        this.redirectLoop = IS_BROWSER;
    }

    getAuthHeaderComponents(signatureMethod: SigMethod = 'PLAINTEXT', token = ''): FullToken {
        const nonce = v4();
        const timestamp = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
        return {
            oauth_consumer_key: this.client_key,
            oauth_nonce: nonce,
            oauth_signature_method: signatureMethod,
            oauth_timestamp: timestamp,
            oauth_token: token,
            oauth_version: '1.0',
        };
    }

    getUnsignedAuthHeader(): string {
        return headerFormat({
            ...REALM_PARAM,
            ...this.getAuthHeaderComponents(),
            oauth_signature: this.client_secret + '%26'
        });
    }

  

   
    setToken(token: Token) {
        this.oauth_token = token.oauth_token;
        this.oauth_token_secret = token.oauth_token_secret;
    }

    async getRequestToken(): Promise<Token> {
        const Authorization = this.getUnsignedAuthHeader();
        let res = await (await this.fetch(this.api_base + '/oauth/request_token', {
            headers: { Authorization }
        })).text();
        const token = qsParse(res);
        this.setToken(token);
        return token;
    }
```

One thing I just noticed, no matter how I shift the code, the error always occurs at line 112

Comment: What is `this.fetch()`?

Comment: this.fetch refers to to this.fetch = window.fetch

Comment: _"I've attempted to use solutions in"_... what exactly did you try? `this.fetch = window.fetch.bind(window)` should work

Comment: I replaced `this.fetch = window.fetch;` with `this.fetch = window.fetch.bind(window)` and I'm receiving the same error. I'm fairly certain I'm replacing it at the right spot, but I could be wrong

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you changed and where. The correct spot would be in the `constructor`, within the `if (IS_BROWSER)` block

Comment: Make sure you clear your browser cache when making changes (ie do a hard reload `Ctrl+Shift+R`)

Comment: I edited the question and did a hard reload and still have the same issue. Additionally, the error always is on line 112 no matter how i shift the code

Comment: Which is line 112? You could also try `this.fetch = (...args) => window.fetch(...args);`

Comment: In this case, line 112 is `async getRequestToken(): Promise<Token> {`, but it if I shift it all up by one its shows the same error at line 112 as `async getRequestToken(): Promise<Token> {`. `this.fetch = (...args) => window.fetch(...args);` did not work even with a hard reload.

Comment: Sounds like the code is definitely cached if the line number doesn't change. Are you sure you're saving changes and the script you're editing is the one being run? Try actually clearing your cache. You can verify the script contents being run using the _Sources_ panel in your browser dev-tools

Comment: I can confirm the sources panel is updating to reflect the code I'm changing in visual studios

Comment: Ok, try something completely different and use `this.fetch = async (...args) => { console.log("FAKE FETCH", ...args); return { text: async () => "FAKE RESPONSE" }; };`. If you still get the same error, then it is not running this code

Comment: Ok, I'm not getting anything in the console. I put it in the `getRwquestToken()` and above `this.fetch =window.fetch.bind(window)`